# Creating a cross domain httpOnly cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, next.js

I have a website running on `localhost:3000`, the user will log in from this website and the server will create httpOnly refresh token, and then the user will be redirected to the dashboard on `localhost:5000`

my question is how can I let `localhost:5000` have access to this refresh token so that once the user will be redirected to `localhost:5000`, the website `localhost:5000` will use this refresh token to generate an access token

on the server, I tried to create a cookie with the following options

```
res.cookie('token', token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  domain: '.localhost',
  path: '/',
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
})
```

on the website hosted on `localhost:5000` I wrap all routers with protected route which is the following

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import styles from './style.module.scss'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import actions from '../../actions'

let isMounted = true
function AuthorizationRouter() {
  const { isAuth, error, user } = useSelector((state) => 
  state.isLoggedIn)

const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
   isMounted && dispatch(actions.users.isUserLoggedIn())
   return () => {
   isMounted = false
 }
}, [])

if (error) {
   console.log('AuthorizationRouter ~ error:', error)
   window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/login'
}

if (isAuth) {
   console.log('AuthorizationRouter ~ user:', user)
   return <Outlet />
}

return (
  <div className={styles.authorizationRouter}>
   <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.logo}>
      <img src='/images/light_blue.png' alt='logo' />
    </div>
    <div className={styles.progress}>
      <div className={styles.progress__bar}>
        <div className={styles.progress__value}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
)}

export default AuthorizationRouter
```

this scenario will be in development mode but in production mode, the main website will be hosted on the main domain and the dashboard will be hosted on the subdomain so also how can I achieve this in production mode as in development mode

**note ==> The dashboard and server are hosted on `localhost:5000`**